# using $? when running several commands in parallel in bash

Tags: bash

I'm creating a startup/shutdown script for WebSEAL.  It's written to allow several instances to be stopped/started in parallel.  The only problem is verifying that it completed without issue.  With other infrastructures, I could simply grep for a particular keyword in the output (which I redirect to a log file), but WebSEAL does not give any success/error message.

Instead, I thought to use the $? to throw the exit status into a dynamic variable that will be checked after the startups have occured (during log consolidation).

Here is the code that starts/stops and then creates the variable

```
${PDCOMMAND} >> ${LOGDIR}/${APP}.txt 2>&1 &
let return_${APP}=$?
```

PDCOMMAND is a valid startup/stop command: aka pdweb start my_instance

APP is the name of the instance: aka my_instance

The goal is that return_${APP} (return_my_instance) will have a value of 0 (success) or 1 (failure) when I check it at a later point in the script.

Are there problems using the $? for a command that may have not technically completed at the time that it was set, or does it set it upon completion of that?  So let's say I have 3 instances

instance_1, instance_2, instance_3

if I ran the following:

```
pdweb start instance1 &
let return_instance_1 = $?
pdweb start instance2 &
let return_instance_2 = $?
pdweb start instance_3 &
let_return_instance_3 = $?
```

would return_instance_[1|2|3] have the correct values if they started in unequal amounts of time?  If instance_3 starts before instance_1, for example, will it still output the result of instance_3 to return_instance_3?

Basically, I'm trying to figure out how the command line treats an asynchronous request in regards to the exit status.

Thanks in advance

Comment: As an aside, you cannot have whitespace around your equals signs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No; the exit status code is only available when the command finishes.  (That's why it's called "exit status".)  If you successfully spawned a service and it is up and running, it does not yet have an exit status.

If I am able to correctly guess what you are trying to accomplish, you could reap the values of `$!` after starting each instance, wait for a "reasonable" time (a few seconds?) and check that the processes you started are still running.  If they have terminated, there was a problem.

Comment: I think what I'll do is take them out of parallel.  That method was better for WebSphere which often takes minutes to start.  I take each of those pids and put them in an array as they're started in parallel and then write each pid to a status file.  Once that loop is done, I run through another loop to wait on each pid.  That way the operator can run a status script to check that file to see what's still waiting.

With WebSEAL, the start/stop time is significantly faster, so it won't be necessary to start them in parallel.  If I remove the &, the $? should be set properly...I think.

Thanks!